# O tipo de um sistema operacional pode ser microkernel + monolítico?

Tags: sistema-operacional

Baseando-se no que se diz que um sistema monolítico reúne todas os `procedures` e linka em um grande binário, onde `procedures` podem chamar outros `procedures`.

O microkernel tem como objetivo minimizar o "serviço" feito diretamente do kernel(terceirizando), seja utilizando uma hierarquia de processos com cada um tendo o seu nível de permissão.

E aí que vem a bala:

1. A desvantagem do monolítico é o problema resolvido pelo uso de microkernels.
2. Desempenho do monolítico é maior.
3. O uso de microkernels me garante maior segurança, como que um driver defeituoso não será capaz de derrubar o meu sistema, pois roda em processo separado e não diretamente no kernel.

Ou seja, é possível uma união destes dois?

Comment: Para quem acha que *off-topic* pode abrir uma discussão no meta sobre o assunto que é um pouco inusitado. Antes de responder consultei o SOen e lá o assunto é bem aceito. Não sei porque aqui não deveria ser então.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Claro que os detalhes do que dá para conciliar depende da arquitetura específica. Tem um [verbete sobre isto na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_kernel). Como bem demonstra o artigo há controvérsias se realmente é híbrido mesmo.

Na minha concepção todos os sistemas mais conhecidos são híbridos. Na **maioria da vezes** soluções híbridas são melhores. Note que "maioria das vezes" significa que as decisões devem ser híbridas também, não podem ser dogmáticas (dogmatismo só serve para experimentos, e olhe lá). E uma das coisas que ajudam confirmar isto é que o *kernel* do Linux hoje não é mais um só binário (*[loadable modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_kernel)*). Não estudo especificamente o assunto então alguém poderá dizer que seria errado classificar o Linux como híbrido, eu respeitaria isso. Só não dá para dizer que algo é ou não é por puro marketing, afinal **todos** os envolvidos com seus produtos vão querer puxar para o lado que mais lhe interessa.

Outro ponto importante é que a terceira premissa já foi desmentida na prática e há controvérsias quanto a segunda, pelo menos em teoria é possível ter um *microkernel* muito rápido, ou pelo menos no mesmo nível que um monolítico.

[Microkernel na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).